# Event Handler on component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, events, components

This is not firing on the component but when I attach my event handler to a div it works. Do I need to pass a prop types function in my child component?

```
const buttonStyle = {
  color: 'red'
};

class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <a className="social-button twitter">
            <i href="#" className="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
        )};
}

class PanelButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('this is:');
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>  
          <div onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}> {/*this works attaching it to a div*/}
            CLick me
            </div>
            <div className="social-buttons">
                <Button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} />{/*does now work attaching it to a component*/}
            </div>
           </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PanelButtons />,  document.querySelector('body'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did basically, is passing a callback called `onClick` to the `Button` component. It will be accessible to you through the component's props.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <a className="social-button twitter" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            <i href="#" className="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
        )};
}
```

once the `Button` component's `a` element is clicked, the callback that you passed will be triggered (and `handleClick` will be called).

Answer (score 2):

An `onClick` on a `<button />` would have worked as you expected.

But this is `<Button />` a component which you created, the `onClick` will be sent as props which you can invoke through an `onClick` on the Button component's `a` tag like below, whose handleClick will callback the actual onClick on your `PanelButtons` component.

```
const buttonStyle = {
  color: 'red'
};

class Button extends React.Component {

    handleClick = (e) => {
      this.props.onClick(e)
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <a className="social-button twitter" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <i href="#" className="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
        )};
}

class PanelButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('this is:');
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>  
          <div onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}> {/*this works attaching it to a div*/}
            CLick me
            </div>
            <div className="social-buttons">
                <Button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} />{/*does now work attaching it to a component*/}
            </div>
           </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PanelButtons />,  document.querySelector('body'));
```

If you just want to add an `onClick` in the `PanelButtons` for each button, just modify your render a little bit like this by adding event listener on the `div` tag.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>  
      <div onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}> {/*this works attaching it to a div*/}
        CLick me
        </div>
        <div className="social-buttons" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
            <Button />{/*does now work attaching it to a component*/}
        </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass down the props into `<Button />` component

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <a className="social-button twitter" {...this.props}>
            <i href="#" className="fa fa-twitter"></i>
          </a>
        )};
}
```

More reading: [JSX spread attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes)